# Someone copied and submitted my code as theirs, what should I do?

Tags: computer-science, plagiarism, code

My firend submitted my code on his assignment without my permission and said if something happens he will take the blame, what should I do now ? I am very stressful

Comment: You've already asked this question here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot be certain that he will take the blame. Furthermore, even if he takes the blame: You may still be in trouble if the administration is of the opinion that you should have spoken up right away.

Many on this site will suggest you report this friend immediately. This is probably the safest course of action. This does however burn your friendship with this person. (I'll leave up to you whether you want to be friends with someone who submits your work without your permission.)

IN THE VERY LEAST, if you do not do anything else: **document everything**. Save the emails where you sent him your code, save the chat conversations of him asking for it, etc. etc.

P.S. If you don't have such emails/conversations in digital format, you could bait them into making an admission of guilt: send a casual message to them along the lines of "About my code you submitted for assignment XXX, I don't appreciate it and I'm worried it will be found out. What will we do if you are found out?"

Comment: If the one who is taking the blame that he submitted without my permission then how I will be in trouble? Could you please explain this point

Comment: @WaleedNoon Both sharing your code/giving answers to another student and submitting someone else's work as your own are likely against the rules. Whatever "blame" they take, you're still responsible. Why did you give them your code?

Comment: I didn’t give him my code but am not sure how he got it

Comment: Am I still in danger as I didn’t share my code to him and he was my firend I think he took picture while I was working and I didn’t sense . I tried my best to protect the and secondly, there is huge difference in my and his report his report is poor quality but in mine I explain everything. I submitted on deadline day but he applied for extension and submitted after 10 days

Comment: @Sadstudent I think your instructor will find that story difficult to believe, but in any case, since you are now aware of the situation they could certainly find you responsible for not reporting it.